# How to connect svn server installed on Centos from Windows

Tags: centos, subversion

I've installed svn server on Centos and success to checkout locally. But when i try to checkout by it's public IP from windows by sliksvn command line there's error:

```
svn co http://mysvnhost/svn/repos

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '...'
svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
svn: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found
```

I think i need to config something to access svnserver through http:// or svn ://. But i dont have any clue to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: please update the question and add the command you use to checkout

Comment: How you "installed svn server on Centos", exactly? Show details (Apache's config, if you expected to have http-served repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should decide which protocol to enable. Following are your choices

```bash
file:// # you can use it only locally - Works out of the box. 
svn://repos # access to repos is done through an svnserve server. Works over the network (port 3690). 
svn+ssh://repos # same as svn://, but through an SSH tunnel (port 22). 
http://repos # It is possible to use WebDAV on a Subversion-aware Apache2 server to access a repository. Works over the network (port 80)
https://repos # Same as http://, but over a secure SSL connection (port 443).
```

This really depends on you, on the security level you want to achieve, on how much effort you want to dedicate to set up subversion and so on.

With `svn co http://mysvnhost/svn/repos` your are trying to use **http** protocol that it may or may not be well configured. The basic requirements for this are following packages : `httpd`, `subversion` and network configuration that allow httpd connection from your clients (usually port 80). You could also protect the access to your repository with `htaccess`

And note the following:

> Please note: If you decide to use http:// or https:// to access SVN,
>   do not use any of the other protocols anymore to write to SVN because
>   the ownerships of the changed files will not match the Apache
>   user/group if you do not use http:// or https://

Give a read at this : https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion